# Download image and use Zoom library

Tags: android

I have an activity that I'm going to display an image and I need to zoom in on it, so I found this lib
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

But my picture comes from a URL I'm using Volley.
How could I use this zoom lib by downloading the image?

```
    Intent callIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle callBundle = callIntent.getBundleExtra("package");

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.monkey));

    GlideApp.with(this).load(callBundle.getString("img")).into(imageView);
```

Glide does not fill the object "SubsamplingScaleImageView"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your question pertains to Volley but you didn't mention that it was a strict requirement. You could use Fresco image library developer by facebook and at that repo they have an example of a Zoomable Image View:
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java

Comment: I did the steps according to the repository, but it is giving error msg:Can not resolve symbol 'ZoomableDraweeView
`view = (ZoomableDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.zoomable);

        ctrl = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setUri(uri).setTapToRetryEnabled(true).build();
        hierarchy = new GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder(getResources())
                .setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER)
                .setProgressBarImage(new ProgressBarDrawable())
                .build();
        view.setController(ctrl);
        view.setHierarchy(hierarchy);`

Comment: Zoomable Drawee View is actually not part of the Fresco Library. So you will need to either copy whats in that repo or make your own version of it to use it.

Comment: How do I down the "samples" folder and use the class in my project? Can I download the entire folder using Android Studio?

Comment: You could either just manually copy and paste those files that you need ( I dont remember needing all of them in the zoomable package) or you can clone the samples repo and do the copy and paste into your project